# Do you have to listen to the mikveh lady?

Tags: halacha, women, mistakes, mikvah-ritual-bath, trust-neemanut

From what I understand when a woman goes to the mikvah there is another woman who watches her immerse (dubbed 'mikveh lady'). Apparently this is for practical reasons to make sure everything is done properly (Igros Moshe Yoreh Deah 1:105). I would like to know if there are practical halachic ramifications of this practice, such as does the woman immersing have to listen to the mikveh lady if she is told that she made a mistake?

For example Sarah watches Esther go to the mikveh. Esther comes out and Sarah says, "Esther you touched the wall", or "some of your hair didn't go in". May Esther say, "No, I'm 100% sure you're wrong"?

Comment: This sounds like a case of *eid echad ne-eman be-issurim*, which would, I think, indicate that one has to listen. However, your last sentence adds an interesting twist (which I think would apply to other *eid echat be-issurim* cases) - where the actor is certain that the *eid* is wrong.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I don't know enough about _eid echad ne-eman be-issurim_ does it apply outside of court?

Comment: nikmasi, me neither. :) I thought outside of court was its primary locus of application.

Comment: It's an interesting halachic question.  As a practical matter, I don't know why one would want to question it rather than dunking again, unless you're dealing with a hyper-critical mikvah lady and you've done this a bunch of times already (in which case you may have other problems).  The information is immediate; it's not like you've gotten out and dried off and only then find out there was a problem.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, good point about the practicality. I think the question ends up being more interesting for its theoretical implications, for *eid echad be-issurim* in general, and perhaps also (and I wonder whether this was part of nikmasi's intent in asking) as part of the theoretical framework on which serious debate about women's roles in the clergy is based (i.e. *serara*, as in the answers [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23501/2)).

Comment: What's wrong with touching a wall?

Comment: @DoubleAA chatzitzah, just ask any mikvah lady

Comment: @nikmasi A mikva lady told you that???

Comment: http://www.nrg.co.il/online/11/ART2/469/510.html?hp=11&cat=1103

Comment: @nikmasi Are you talking about a פשוטי כלי עץ stepladder built into the wall, on which גזירת מרחצאות של כלים could apply (YD 198:31)? Otherwise, if she got her hands wet from the mikva before she touched the wall, and she wasn't pressing hard against the wall, is the custom to still be machmir for גזירה שמא לא ירפה as well as treating *hadacha* as b'dieved?

Comment: Nothing wrong with touching the wall, it's a common misconception, no basis in halachah! But in order that the tevilah should be valid, it's not enough that the all the hair goes in, the hair is not allowed to touch the surface of the water...

Answer (score -3):

According to what it says in SA YD [281:5](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01044.html#HtmpReportNum0279_L2) and in [16:11](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01044.html#HtmpReportNum0015_L2) she would be believed.

Comment: Could you please include quotations and/or summaries?

Comment: ...and clarify which "she" you refer to?

Comment: (After checking those two paragraphs on the linked-to page.) ... and state how you derive your conclusion from those paragraphs? −1.

Comment: is there a reason that one should distrust the mikvah lady?