# Pictures of married women before they were married - hair uncovered

Tags: marriage, hair, hair-covering

Is there any reason whatsoever to not look at, or to not display in the house (or submit for job interviews, or use as profile picture on social media, etc etc), pictures of a married women, before she was married, with her hair uncovered?

Comment: See the end of this paragraph, if i recall אוצר פוסקים על אבן העזר סימן כא brings אחרונים that bring this as a proof, but I don't have the sefer available to look it up https://www.sefaria.org/Avot_DeRabbi_Natan.2.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: Similarly pictures of babies in diapers without full length dresses

Comment: @DoubleAA No. I didn't think it was necessary, but to clarify - pictures where she is an adult, and could possibly be confused as a recent, post-marriage picture, or create some sort of stumbling block, or similar

Comment: Similar, but more specific: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18271/is-a-picture-of-a-woman-prior-to-marriage-with-hair-uncovered-considered-ervah-o?rq=1

Comment: @RabbiK not sure what you mean, any picture could be a stumbling block, what does marriage have to do with anything if not a formal status change of the body part in question

Comment: @DoubleAA It seems pretty clear that there is no halachic issue here, hence I've left out the halacha tag, but I am fishing in the dark for any discussions that might raise any issues that I haven't been able to think about. This question is coming more from my gut than a logical argument

Comment: Should one be looking at pictures of women in general, whether married or not?

Comment: @יהושעק not the direction I am going. Maybe consider questions like "if submitting a picture for a job interview, or chosing a profile picture in social media, would there be any preference to have a post-marriage hair-covered picture?"

Comment: That's a much more interesting question, @RabbiKaii! I will say, l'maaseh, every married religious woman I see on LinkedIn is wearing a kisuy rosh / wig in their profile picture.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a Woman be a Shul President? How about a member of Knesset?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37437/can-a-woman-be-a-shul-president-how-about-a-member-of-knesset)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18271/is-a-picture-of-a-woman-prior-to-marriage-with-hair-uncovered-considered-ervah-o